# I want to get a input of a number of any length then i want to convert it to word form. For example if i input 615, it should print ' six one five'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
diction = {
    0 : "zero",
    1 : "one",
    2 : "two",
    3 : "three",
    4 : "four",
    5 : "five",
    6 : "six",
    7 : "seven",
    8 : "eight",
    9 : "nine",
    }
n = int(input("Input a number: "))
print (diction[n])
```

this is my code but it only works if i input a single digit number.
It returns an error when inputted more than 1 digit. How do I solve that?

Answer (score 5):

You need to iterate over the inputted number, one number at a time, and look it up in your dict:

```
diction = {
    0 : "zero",
    1 : "one",
    2 : "two",
    3 : "three",
    4 : "four",
    5 : "five",
    6 : "six",
    7 : "seven",
    8 : "eight",
    9 : "nine",
}
n = int(input("Input a number: "))
print (' '.join(diction[int(x)] for x in str(n)))
```

Note that since you have to iterate over a string, and then convert it back to int to look up in the dict, it might be easier to store the keys int he dict as string.

EDIT: If you want to get the full English name for a number, e.g. `465` is `four hundred and sixty five`, you might want to look at the [inflect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inflect) package.

Comment: May as well keep `n` as a string rather than convert back and forth

Comment: Yep - I say that after the code block (didn't explicitly make this change though, in case OP has a reason to use ints as keys).

Answer (score 4):

```
diction = {
    0 : "zero",
    1 : "one",
    2 : "two",
    3 : "three",
    4 : "four",
    5 : "five",
    6 : "six",
    7 : "seven",
    8 : "eight",
    9 : "nine",
    }

n = int(input("Input a number: "))
for i in str(n):
  print (diction[int(i)])
```

Comment: you can use print (diction[int(i)],end=' ') also to get output in one line

Answer (score 1):

This is one way. `toolz.compose` is useful for processing multiple functions on an interable. You may also see a small performance improvement versus a generation expression.

```
from toolz import compose

diction = {
    0 : "zero",
    1 : "one",
    2 : "two",
    3 : "three",
    4 : "four",
    5 : "five",
    6 : "six",
    7 : "seven",
    8 : "eight",
    9 : "nine",
    }

n = input("Input a number: ")

print(' '.join(map(compose(diction.get, int), list(n))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go full ninja:

```
# pip install inflect
import inflect
p = inflect.engine()

print (' '.join(p.number_to_words(x) for x in input("Input a number: ")))
```

No variables, just code.

Always look for available packages when solving already solved problems. Your assignment seemed school like, and I'd argue its more use in a teaching environment to teach students how to use packages...

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
ints = map(int, str(n)) #if you dont convert input its easier!
dictions = map(diction.get, ints)
result = ' '.join(dictions)
print(result)
```